# How to output in HTML all objects from Django database?

Tags: python, django

I just started learning Python and Django.
Trying to output on HTML data from the database, I can do it if I set a id, but I wanna have a page where I list all the data from the database in a table.

This is my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import clientes, viagem

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    ls= clientes.objects.all()    
    context= {'ls': ls}
    return render(request, "booking/home.html", context)
```

And this is my page:

```
{% extends 'bulma/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Travel{% endblock %}

{% for clientes in clientes %}
{% block content %}


    <table class="table is-fullwidth is-hoverable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><abbr title="ID">ID</abbr></th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Apelido</th>
            <th>Morada</th>
            <th>Telemóvel</th>
            <th>NIF</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>{{ls.id}}</th>
            <td>{{ls.nome}}</td>
            <td>{{ls.apelido}}</td>
            <td>{{ls.morada}}</td>
            <td>{{ls.tel}}</td>
            <td>{{ls.nif}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

{% endblock content %}
{% endfor %}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `{% for clientes in clientes %}` cannot work because `clientes` isn't defined in your context. `ls` is what you pass to your context. Also look at your loop further, it's not a good idea to name the individual item in your loop the same as the collection you're looping through (`for clientes in clientes`) as this means you're redefining `clientes`. And finally, if you loop like this `for item in some_list` then each item inside the loop is called `item`.

Comment: You should do the django tutorial, then you'd have read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something) which shows exactly how to list all the instances of a model.

Comment: Also read about how template blocks work [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance)

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks for the documentation suggestion! Will read it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: your `{% for %}` loop is not at the right place. When extending another template, only the code in `{% block %}` statements are executed. So you want to move your loop inside the `{% block content %}`.

Second point: in the context you pass to the template, your queryset is named `ls`, not `clientes`, so you want to change this name either in the view or the template - the point is that they have to match xD.

A possible correction:

```
def index(request):
    queryset = clientes.objects.all()    
    context= {'clientes': queryset}
    return render(request, "booking/home.html", context)
```

and

```
{% extends 'bulma/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Travel{% endblock %}

{% block content %}


{% for client in clientes %}
    <table class="table is-fullwidth is-hoverable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><abbr title="ID">ID</abbr></th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Apelido</th>
            <th>Morada</th>
            <th>Telemóvel</th>
            <th>NIF</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>{{client.id}}</th>
            <td>{{client.nome}}</td>
            <td>{{client.apelido}}</td>
            <td>{{client.morada}}</td>
            <td>{{client.tel}}</td>
            <td>{{client.nif}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
{% endfor %}       
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I'd still expect the loop to be positioned differently (around the table rows) rather than having multiple tables. But I guess that's the next step...

Comment: For loop should be in <tbody> otherwise number of tables will be equals to number of clientes records

Comment: That was great! Thanks! I had already arrived at the solution for the views, but it was the out of place `{% for %}` that was messing it all up. For some reason, before when I got it into the place it is now, that table just wouldn't appear.

Comment: @dirkgroten I just noticed that it creates multiple tables. Well, as I said, I just started learning it!

Comment: @dirkgroten yes I deliberately left this out ;-)

Comment: @Harshiljain well, I assume this is indeed what the OP really wants, but who am I to decide for someone else ?-)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
{% extends 'bulma/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Travel{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <table class="table is-fullwidth is-hoverable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><abbr title="ID">ID</abbr></th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Apelido</th>
            <th>Morada</th>
            <th>Telemóvel</th>
            <th>NIF</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for client in ls %} # ls as you passed variable named ls
            <tr>
              <th>{{client.id}}</th>
              <td>{{client.nome}}</td>
              <td>{{client.apelido}}</td>
              <td>{{client.morada}}</td>
              <td>{{client.tel}}</td>
              <td>{{client.nif}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: An answer should not consist of just code, but should explain the differences and why this is a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### you must write this code in view.py

```
def product_detail_view(request):
   obj = product.objects.all()
   context = { 'allobject' : obj }
   return render(request, "product/details.html", context)
```

#### you have to write this code in your html file

```
   {% extends 'base.html' %}
   {% block content %}
   <h1> New about </h1>
   <p>
       {% for item in allobject %}
            {{ item.title }}
       {% endfor %}
   </p>
 {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% block content %}
{% for x in y %}
{% autoescape off %}
{{x}}
{% endautoescape %} 
{% endfor%}
```

This is quite simple to execute. Use the tools that django provides :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try it:

```
{% extends 'bulma/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Travel{% endblock %}

{% for clientes in ls%}
{% block content %}


    <table class="table is-fullwidth is-hoverable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><abbr title="ID">ID</abbr></th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Apelido</th>
            <th>Morada</th>
            <th>Telemóvel</th>
            <th>NIF</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>{{ls.id}}</th>
            <td>{{ls.nome}}</td>
            <td>{{ls.apelido}}</td>
            <td>{{ls.morada}}</td>
            <td>{{ls.tel}}</td>
            <td>{{ls.nif}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

{% endblock content %}
{% endfor %}
```

You need to use the same name of the dict in your forloop.